# c# Try Statement issue converting from VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have this piece of code which is calling some functions in a web service. however the original was written in VB and when I have converted it it gives me an error in my c# stating that 'The name Information does not exist in the current context' I have checked the VB and it win there either! any thoughts?

Code

```
try {
        Atlas.ah21 oAh21 = new Atlas.ah21();
        oAh21.session_id = sessionID;
        oAh21.input = txtPostcode.Text;
        oAh21.data = "";
        Atlas.arrayOfAddress oAddresses = oAtlas.ah21(oAh21);

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        string s = null;

    for (x = 0; x <= oAddresses.address.Length - 1; x++)
    {
        s = "";
        for (y = 0; y <= Information.UBound(oAddresses.address(x).LABEL.item); y++)
        {
            if (s.Length > 0)
            {
                s = s + ", ";
            }
            s = s + oAddresses.address(x).LABEL.item(y);
        }
        lstMatches.Items.Add(s);
    }

        txtStatus.Text = "Ready. ";

        if (oAddresses.address.Length > 1) {
            txtStatus.Text = txtStatus.Text + Convert.ToString(oAddresses.address.Length) + " matches found.";
        } else {
            txtStatus.Text = txtStatus.Text + Convert.ToString(oAddresses.address.Length) + " match found.";
        }
} catch {
    txtStatus.Text = "Error";
} finally {
        btnSearch.Enabled = true;
}
```

Please excuse the amount of code however i think it necessary in the context of this question.

Comment: It would help to see the VB code you are converting from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know VB but i think UBound is just returning the length of the collection so you would do

```
for (y = 0; y <= oAddresses.address[x].LABEL.item.Length; y++)
```

Further to your comment i have realised that address(x) should be address[x].  In c# you only use () for method calls, indexers use [].  In VB they both use () i think.

Comment: thanks for this it seems to sole one issue any reason I might be getting this now? Non-invocable member 'SageCRMAtlas.Atlas.arrayOfAddress.address' cannot be used like a method. I have used the oAddresses.addrss else where and it works fine

Comment: Thanks for this it works now I am into debug and trying to work out errors a last question can you tell me how to print an error in c# on to the screen?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by "The Screen". You can output to the console with Console.WriteLine(); but thats the same in vb.

Answer (score 2):

The [Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.information.aspx) class is a special helper Module written for VB that is not available in C# projects by default. But you can still use it if you reference the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly and also add `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;` in your class.

The following trivial C# snippet will compile and run if you add the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll assembly to your project:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsDate("");
    }
}
```

Also your `Information.UBound` function will compile just fine if you follow the two steps described above.

Comment: is there a way to better express the for statement in c# I am learning and thought that it would be a great plan to convert from vb to c# and pick it apart line by line but i am really stuck! :(

Comment: Classes in the Microsoft.VisualBasic can be used in c#, you just need to reference the right assembly.

Comment: @Justin: THere's not too many things you could do with a for loop except clean up the code blcok i.e. extract it to a separate method.

Comment: @Ben: My answer did eventually state the same thing as your comment above. I did simplify the answer and hopefully it will make more sense with less verbiage.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if `Information.UBound` should be a static call.  Have you included the required namespace (i.e., the namespace which includes the `Information` type) via a `using` statement at the top of the file?  For example:

```
namespace Whatever
{
    class Information { }
}

// in your file

using Whatever;  // now the Information class is visible in your file
```

Answer (score 0):

VB UBound is equivalent of c# `Array.GetUpperBound(...)` see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getupperbound.aspx. So the c# implementation of UBound would be something like that:

```
public static int UBound(Array array, int dimension)
{
    if (Array == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    }

    return array.GetUpperBound(dimension-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UBound for VB but C# remove it and add length after parameter.

**VB**

```
For i = 0 To UBound(params)
   cmd.Parameters.Add(params(i))
Next (i)
```

**C#**

```
for (i = 0; i <= @params.Length; i++)
  {
    cmd.Parameters.Add(@params[i]);
  }
```

Thanks,
Fadão